# How to solve this Integral equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations, differential-equations

```
D[x[t] - x[t - 1]/(2 E), {t, 3}] + Integrate[E^(-δ)*x[t - δ]/5^t, {δ, 2, 2.5}] == 0
```

I found solve this problem is hard with Mathematica.

I also find a article **[here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/IntegralEquations/IntegralEquations.pdf)** about how to deal with Integral equation with Mathematica code.

But my function is implicit function in the equation,so how to solve this problem?

Comment: You might have a look at the several responses to prior questions on integral equations in MSE.

Comment: Three boundary condition are needed to solve this equation.  What are they?  Also, you may find it beneficial to replace `x[t]` by `y[t]=x[t] - x[t - 1]/(2 E)` as the dependent variable.

Comment: Then how to solve this? in fact the solution will go to 0 when t-> infinity ,but don't always be a constant.And I don't know how to transform the equation to x(t)=... like the equations in that article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Large *t* Approximation**

Because this is a neutral delay integral-differential equation, solving it may seem very difficult at first glance.  However, the term `1/5^t` makes the integral negligible for *t* greater than about 2. So, with the integral ignored for large *t*, the equation can be reduced to

```
x[t] - x[t - 1]/(2 E) = c[2] t^2 + c[1] t + c[0]
```

where the constants *c* are determined by boundary conditions.  The solution to this difference equation is

```
x[t] = Sum[f[t - n] (2 E)^-n, {n, 1, N}] + x[t - N] (2 E)^-N
```

Because this series converges very rapidly for `N>3`, *N* can be set to infinity for large *t*, yielding

```
(t^2*c[2])/(-1 + 2*E) + (t*((-1 + 2*E)*c[1] - 4*E*c[2]))/(1 - 2*E)^2 
+ ((1 - 2*E)^2*c[0] + 2*E*(c[1] - 2*E*c[1] + c[2] + 2*E*c[2]))/(-1 + 2*E)^3
```

**Approximate Solution Including Integral**

According to the [Wolfram discussion of delay differential equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html), `NDSolve` cannot solve the complete original equation.  However, if `x[t - δ]` in the integrand is approximated by linear interpolation, then the integral can be performed.  For instance,

```
n = 5;
Piecewise[Table[{x[t - 2 - 0.5 i/n] + (x[t - 2 - 0.5 (i + 1)/n] - 
 x[t - 2 - 0.5 i/n]) 2 n δ, 0.5 i/n <= δ <= 0.5 (i + 1)/n}, {i, 0, n - 1}]];
int = Simplify[5^-t Integrate[Exp[-(δ + 2)] %, {δ, 0, .5}]]
```

to yield

```
(0.03877636669329322*x[-2.5 + t] + 0.003170210316893817*x[-2.4 + t] + 0.0025002000402758024*x[-2.3 + t] 
  + 0.001654193122766361*x[-2.2 + t] + 0.0006025810391796899*x[-2.1 + t] + 0.006546733400304792*x[-2. + t])/5^t
```

and `NDSolve` can solve the resulting equation:

```
NDSolve[{x'''[t] - x'''[t - 1]/(2 E) + int == 0, x[t /; t <= 0] == ϕ[t]}, x, {t, -3, 100}]
```

where `ϕ[t]` is the initial condition for the equation.  Choosing

```
ϕ[t] = -HeavisidePi[t] + 2 HeavisidePi[t + 1] - HeavisidePi[t + 2]
```

which is a challenging initial condition for many delay differential equations, gives

[image]

Note that this curve can be fitted to a quadratic polynomial at an accuracy of better than 0.000001 for `t > 2`, validating the large *t* approximation presented in the first half of this Answer.

1 Dec 14 update: Integral treated with improved accuracy.  c[3] deleted.

Comment: I am confused,how to obtain the equation "x[t] = Sum[f[t - n - 1/2] (2 E)^-n, {n, 1, N}] + x[t - N] (2 E)^-N"? I don't uderstand.And t solution is not sufficient,you think it may have a numerical solution? Does the article above makes some help?

Comment: p.s:the solution is a Non-oscillatory solution,so x(infinity)->0  maybe most important.Can you explian use a boundary conition use what's you think?

Comment: @user15961, the article you mentioned is about solving integral equations.  Your equation is much more general, so I do not believe that the article will help much.  However, I do believe that the equation can be solved numerically.  To help you make progress, I need to know the range of *t* in which you are interested and the boundary conditions.

Comment: the equation is experimental.so boundary condition is also a experiment.the t range from 0 to 100.i guess it is difficult.

Comment: @user15961, NDSolve will require numerical boundary conditions to solve this equation.  Additionally, `x[t]` must be specified numerically for `0>t>-2.5` in order to evaluate `x[t]` for `t>0`.  Please provide your best estimates.  Also, please consider my solution above, if you have not done so already.  It should be quite general and accurate for large t. If you know the asymptotic behavior of the solution, it may be possible to constrain `f[t]`.

Comment: Can you provide your mathematica code?I guess the formula you provided don't handle by hand.

Comment: @user15961, I derived the first two equations by inspection, although you can verify their accuracy by back substitution.  I obtained the third equation by executing the second equation in MMA for `N -> Infinity`.  The rest of the code is provided, except for the process of fitting the curve shown by a cubic.  The code for this is `fit = FindFit[Table[{i, x[i] /. First[sol]}, {i, 92, 100, .1}], 
a + b y + c y^2 + d y^3, {a, b, c, d}, y]`.  As you can see, all this is quite simple, once one realizes how to proceed.

Comment: @user15961, did this Answer meet your needs?  Best wishes.

Comment: yeah but I still don't know how to get equation two from equation one.

Comment: Use `RSolve[x[n] - x[n - 1]/(2 E) - f[n] == 0, x[n], n]`.  At first glance, the result may not look like the second equation, but it is.  Hope this helps.

Comment: you made a fantastic answer and I am learning the core of your answer. Thanks indeed!