# Solving a nasty partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a differential equation that I would like to solve numerically in the region $z \in [0,L]$ and $t \in [0,t_{max}]$:

$$
\partial_t S(z,t) = f(z)S(z,t) + \int_0^L \text{d} z'g(z,z') S(z',t),
$$
where $f(z)$ and $g(z,z')$ are complex-valued functions.As an initial condition I woud like to consider something like $S(z,0) = \exp(-(z-L/5)^2)$.

So somehow I have to use Mathematicas `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate` in one procedure. If the integral would not be there, I would just `NDSolve`. In fact I tried something naive like

```
NDSolve[{D[S[z, t], t] == f[z] S[z, t] + 
  NIntegrate[g[z, zprime] S[zprime, t], {zprime, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], 
  S[z, 0] == Exp[-(z - L/5)^2]}, S, {t, 0, tsteps}, {z, 0, L}]
```

but Mathematica does not like this at all. Any thoughts about how I should deal with this problem? Ultimately I would like to find an interpolating function for $S$, which I can then plot dynamically.

Comment: to use numerical solving functions you need to define all the variables like alpha, beta and L

Comment: @k_v I did this, I just did not display it here.

Comment: Please provide those quantities, including `f` and `g`, in your question.

Comment: Once refer to this link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200270/solving-partial-differential-equation-involving-hilbert-transform/200299?noredirect=1#comment519626_200299. You equation is similar to that of in the link.
You have mentioned directly the integral, where as in that question hilbert transform is mentioned. I think you can figure it out. So you just change the function and boundary values and I think you get the answer thereafter.

Answer (score 4):

I corrected several syntax errors by editing your equation (parentheses to brackets, `z'` to `zprime`) in your Question, and also manufactured some simple expressions for the four undefined quantities:

```
L = 1; tsteps = 1; f[z_] := 1; g[z_, zprime_] := 1
```

With these changes, `NDSolve` runs but, not surprisingly, generates errors:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand S[zprime,t] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-\[Infinity],0.}}. >>
NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve. >>
```

To the best of my knowledge, `NDSolve` cannot solve integro-differential equations.  However, similar equations have been addressed before.  See, for instance, [66800](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66800/how-to-solve-this-integral-equation/66812) and references therein.  In essence, `S` is approximated by a `Piecewise` function and the resulting coupled ordinary differential equations solved using `NDSolve`.