# Solving partial integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, interpolation, integral-equations

I want to solve a partial integro-differential equation of this form:

[image]

using NDSolve, something like

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x] - D[u[t, x]*int[w (s)*u[t, x + s]], {s, -L, L}],x] + u[t,x] * (1-u[t,x]), u[0, x] == u0, u[t, -L] == u[t, L],u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, 0, 2 xend}],
```

but can't find how to interpolate such integral with Simpson's rule or something similar. Any idea?

Comment: Imgur is down here so I can't see your image at the moment, but have you checked the post under the tag [integral-equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-equations?tab=Votes)?

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look at the posts under the tag you suggested, but as I'm new in Mathematica didn't manage to solve the problem due to the complexity of the equation and the way the integral is defined. Do you know if I need to interpolate the integral before adding it to the NDSolve?

Comment: Yes, certain pre-processing is necessary, because currently `NDSolve` can't directly handle integro-differential equation.

Comment: @maths56 Add the definition of $\omega(s)$ and $R(n)$ to make the discussion useful.

Comment: @AlexTrounev ω(s) can be a Gaussian and R(n) is the reaction term and can be a logistic growth function, I just added them in the picture. I initially omitted some bits as it is a system that I need to solve, but the integral in this equation causes me the problem

Comment: Try using the Fourier method from my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200270/solving-partial-differential-equation-involving-hilbert-transform/200299#200299

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks a lot. Do you know how I can then take the derivative of the integral wrt x? I tried some things, but din't work.

Comment: @maths56 See my answer.

Comment: What process is modeling this integro-differential equation?

Answer (score 5):

I use the code from my answer on [Solving partial differential equation involving Hilbert transform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200270/solving-partial-differential-equation-involving-hilbert-transform/200299#200299)

We put $\mu =0,\sigma^2 =1/2$,`L=Infinity`,`n[0,x]==Cos[x]`

```
n = Sum[f[m][t] Exp[I m x], {m, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Then the integral is calculated as

```
 Integrate[
 Exp[-s^2] Exp[I m s]/Sqrt[Pi], {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*Out[]= E^(-(m^2/4))*)
```

Now we can make a system of equations

```
nn = 137; tm = 1.; eq = 
 Table[-f[m]'[t] - m^2 f[m][t] - 
    I m Sum[If[Abs[m - k] <= nn, f[m - k][t], 0] Exp[-k^2/4] f[k][
        t], {k, -nn, nn}] + f[m][t] - 
    Sum[If[Abs[m - k] <= nn, f[m - k][t], 0] f[k][t], {k, -nn, nn}] ==
    0, {m, -nn, nn}];
ic = Table[
   f[m][0] == (KroneckerDelta[m, 1] + KroneckerDelta[m, -1])/
     2, {m, -nn, nn}];
var = Table[f[i], {i, -nn, nn}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, var, {t, 0, tm}];
```

Data visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[Re[
     Sum[sol[[m + 1]][t] Exp[I (-nn + m) x], {m, 0, 2*nn}]], {t, 0, 
     tm, .2}]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Blue, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],
  Plot3D[Re[
   Sum[sol[[m + 1]][t] Exp[I (-nn + m) x], {m, 0, 2*nn}]], {t, 0., 
   tm}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figire 1]

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for asking more questions, but I'm very new to this and I don't understand every step of your code. Is the above code part of your previous code in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200270/solving-partial-differential-equation-involving-hilbert-transform/200299#200299? Cause when I run the above I got "General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation."

Comment: Check first `$Version`. What do you have, what version?

Comment: I've got version 11.0.1

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy the line of code `sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, var, {t, 0, tm}];`. Corrected. Check it out.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. I've got a few questions though. First, how is the IC translated with the KroneckerDelta? So if I want a Gaussian for ICs or anything else what would be the correct command line? Also, when I increased the tm I got "NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 1.0963228918206627`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." and further messages. I was planning to run for tmax=100, is this possible? And finally, have you done something similar for a system? In my case there is one more reaction-diffusion pde and one ode.

Comment: If there is a system, then the solution will be different. Show the system and all the data, then we will discuss.